# Function "is not a function" in Truffle dev

Tags: truffle-console

I am not sure why I am being told my function is not a function.

I am doing calls as I always do from the Truffle console.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract store {
    string public storage_;

    function store_it(string memory s) public {
        storage_=s;
    }
}
```

`stor = store.at(store.address)`

`stor.store_it("string")`

`TypeError: stor.store_it is not a function`

What is going wrong?

Comment: My guess is some breaking changes in a Truffle update, check https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0#user-content-what-s-new-in-truffle-v5-truffle-migrate-async-migrations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are using truffle v5. In that version you have to use `await` to obtain the result of `.at`

```
stor = await store.at(store.address)
stor.store_it("string")
```

Answer (score 1):

In truffle version 5.0, you have to use `await` to obtain the result of contract.

```
let contract = await ContractName.deployed()
let result = await contract.functionName()
```